# elements of a finite field vs its characteristic

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> What is the difference saying, '' a finite field with $q$ elements'' or ''a field with characteristic $p$'' ?

a finite field must be of prime characteristic and vice versa, what is the difference then, must $q$ be some combination of $p$ ?

Comment: A field with characteristic $p$ could for one thing be infinite. But yes, $q$ must be a power of $p$.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft do you have an example for the first case

Comment: Take the field of fractions of $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ for example.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft why necessarily the field of fractions, is $\mathbb F_p[x]$ not enough ?

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ is not a field.